# Application displaying latest blog posts on desktop

Tags: linux-mint, kde, rss-aggregator

Is there an application for Linux which is able to put rss feed directly on desktop? I've seen lots of standalone programs, but I'd like to have a window in the corner of my desktop always showing latest n entries (like a desklet).

I'm using Linux Mint with KDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`conky`](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) to display RSS feeds directly on your desktop. Here's an example:

```
# --- Window Layout & Options --- #
#background yes
own_window yes
own_window_colour brown
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_type override
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
use_spacer right
use_xft yes
alignment middle_middle
gap_x 20
gap_y 60

# --- Colours, Sizes, Fonts & Margins --- #
update_interval 2.0
maximum_width 300
stippled_borders 3
border_margin 9
border_width 10
default_color grey

# --- Text --- #
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
font Monospace:size=8:weight=bold
uppercase no
draw_shades yes

TEXT
${font}The Pirate Bay - Blog${hr 2}
${font}${rss http://rss.thepiratebay.se/blog 1 item_titles 10}

${font}Linux Outlaws Podcast${hr 2}
${font}${rss http://feeds.feedburner.com/linuxoutlaws-ogg 1 item_titles 10}

${font}ArchLinux News Feed${hr 2}
${font}${rss http://www.archlinux.org/feeds/news/ 1 item_titles 10}

${font}ArchLinux Repo Updates${hr 2}
```

Put the above in a file called `$HOME/.conky/conky_rss.conf`, and then run it like so:

```
$ conky -c $HOME/.conky/conky_rss.conf
```

Which results in the above RSS feeds displaying on my desktop like this:

[image: ss of conky rss]

`conky` can do a lot more than this.  Take a look at its website for examples.

Comment: Mate, this looks fantastic! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of people use [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) for this sort of task. The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Conky#Display_RSS_feeds) has the details.

There is also a [long thread on the Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=39906&p=1) with plenty of examples of this functionality.

There are also lots of blog posts that may be of assistance in setting this up, eg., http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_add_an_RSS_feed_to_Conky

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, since you're using KDE you may also be interested in KDE specific apps for this task.

### KDE Official RSS Plasmoid

A plasmoid specifically designed for showing feeds on the desktop is called RSSnow:

[image]

its included in the [plasma-widgets-addons](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/plasma-widgets-addons) package. You can have all sorts of transparency effects if you wish, it depends on your plasma theme. I hate transparent stuff so what you see is just the result on my desktop.

### Plasmoid Scripts from KDE-Look

You may also find some non-official RSS plasmoid in KDE-Look:

http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/FeedView?content=154877

http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Latest+news?content=155940

these are plasmoid scripts to be installed via Get Hot New Stuff:

-right click on the desktop

-select "add new widgets"

-select "get new widgets"

-select "download new plasma widgets" and search for them

both only show one RSS feed at a time but you can have more than one instance running.

### Plasmoid Binaries from KDE-Look

On KDE-Look you may also find a couple of plasmoid binaries:

http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/rssremix?content=102542

http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Plasma+Feed?content=118140

you need to download the source code and compile it for them to work, but they seem to be a bit outdated judging from the last update date.

Answer (score 0):

RSS isn't so easy as it used to be.
I suggest you use Liferea to add and update the feeds - as they update, you'll get notifications.
Conky can show what feeds are available, but you can't 'click and go' there unless the feed goes to notifications.

This is something that should, really, be a fundamental applet (part of messaging) for KDE or (in my case) Cinnamon.