# What does Conky update interval update and how to tune it?

Tags: conky

As I understand, `conky_update` reloads the whole conky window every time. So, if I have rss fetching there and some scripts running they all rerun every few seconds. Is this right? Can I make the rss fetching part be very infrequent (say, every 10 hours), but other parts with few-seconds updating?

Relevant part from my .conkyrc:

```
update_interval 2.0

TEXT
${if_match ${desktop_number}==4}
${font GE Inspira:size=12}${color White}${alignc}Recent Blog Posts${color}${font}
${color White}${hr 1}${color}
${execp python ~/Documents/rss.py}
${color White}${hr 1}${color}
${endif}
```

rss.py merely scans an rss feed and gets blog post titles & dates from it.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86222/application-displaying-latest-blog-posts-on-desktop/86226#86226

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [conky documentation notes](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html), there is a `rss` variable that defaults to a 15 minute interval for checking feeds:

> Download and parse RSS feeds. The interval may be a floating point value greater than 0, otherwise defaults to 15 minutes. Action may be one of the following: feed_title, item_title (with num par), item_desc (with num par) and item_titles (when using this action and spaces_in_front is given conky places that many spaces in front of each item). This object is threaded, and once a thread is created it can't be explicitly destroyed. One thread will run for each URI specified. You can use any protocol that Curl supports.

The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Conky#Display_RSS_feeds) has an example:

```
${rss https://planet.archlinux.org/rss20.xml 1 item_titles 10 }
```

Where the `1` is a one-minute interval and `10` of the most recent updates are displayed.

If you intend on using a custom script, then there is a conky variable that supports an independent interval, `execpi`:

> Same as execp but with specific interval. Interval can't be less than update_interval in configuration. Note that the output from the $execpi command is still parsed and evaluated at every interval.

Comment: Yes, that does work for a default rss command. However as you can see from my post I'm running a custom script (because I wanted some additional functionality). So my question is about customizing the execp command.

Comment: Then you should use `execpi`...

Comment: @sashkello Done... Hope that helps.